# Opportunity Contact Role - Report including record ID

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, junction-object, opportunitycontactrole

My users need to create reports on Opportunities and Opportunity Contact Roles that would include the Opportunity Contact Role ID.

Supposedly because this is a junction object, the record ID field can't be added to the report type. It is just not visible under Fields Available for Reports.
I also tried creating a formula field on the Opportunity Contact Role object referring to the object's ID. Again, the field is not available when creating the formula text.

Obviously, the IDs could be downloaded via data loader but the users need this possibility directly in the reporting functionality of Salesforce.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went into my dev org, created a custom formula field of type TEXT called `ID_18` and defined it as

```
CASESAFEID(Id)
```

After saving, I could add to my custom report type Opportunities with Contact Roles

Comment: Thank you, This worked for me as well!